# Why the quarter in the $\frac{1}{4}$-pinched sphere theorem?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Is there any hope of a high-level explanation of why the fraction $\frac{1}{4}$ 
plays such a prominent role as a 
[sectional curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sectional_curvature)
bound in Riemannian geometry?
My (dim) understanding is that the idea is that if the sectional curvature of a manifold is
constrained to be close to 1, then the manifold must be topologically a (homeomorphic to the)
sphere $S^n$.
Conjectured by Hopf and Rauch, proved by Berger and Klingenberg, and strengthened by
Brendel and Schoen to establish diffeomorphism to $S^n$.
Here is the definition of "local" *$\frac{1}{4}$-pinched* from
Brendel and Schoen's paper "Manifolds with $1/4$-pinched curvature
are space forms"
(*J. Amer. Math. Soc.*, 22(1): 287-307, January 2009;
[PDF](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2009-22-01/S0894-0347-08-00613-/S0894-0347-08-00613-9.pdf)):

> We will say that a manifold $M$ has pointwise $1/4$-pinched sectional curvatures if $M$ has positive sectional curvature and for every point $p \in M$ the ratio of the maximum to the minimum sectional curvature at that point is less than 4.

I know the "$\frac{1}{4}$" in the 
[$\frac{1}{4}$-pinched sphere theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_theorem)
is optimal,
and perhaps that is the answer to my question: $\frac{1}{4}$ appears because the theorem
is false otherwise—punkt!
But I am wondering if there is a high-level intelligble reason for the appearance of $\frac{1}{4}$,
rather than, say, $\frac{3}{8}$, or $\frac{e}{\pi^2}$ for that matter?

I am aware this is a "fishing expedition," and a fair response is: 
Study the Brendel-Schoen proof closely, and enlightenment will follow!

Comment: A funny fact is that in odd dimension, since there are no compact rank one symmetric spaces, one can sow that the differetiable sphere theorem holds for $1/4-\epsilon(n)$-pinched manifolds (globally), this is a theorem by Ni and Wilking if I remember correctly. However, no meaningful etimates on $\epsilon(n)$ are known, except in dimension 5 (work of Berger).

Answer (score 12):

The new proofs add a layer of complication that is unnecessary for your question. From Cheeger and Ebin, *Comparison Theorems in Riemannian Geometry* first paragraph of Chapter 6:

> The symmetric spaces of positive
>   curvature are known to admit metrics
>   such that $1 \geq K_M \geq
> > \frac{1}{4}$; see Example 3.38. In
>   fact, we will prove that any
>   riemannian manifold with $1 \geq K_M
> > \geq \frac{1}{4},$ which is not a
>   sphere, is *isometric* to one of these
>   spaces.

Back in chapter 3, page 73,

> A complete classification of symmetric
>   spaces is available (Helgason [1962]).
>   In particular, the only simply
>   connected symmetric spaces having
>   positive curvature are the spheres of
>   constant curvatures, complex and
>   quaternionic projective spaces, and
>   the Cayley plane. These are sometimes
>   referred to as the *rank one*
>   symmetric spaces, and except for the
>   spheres they have canonical metrics
>   varying between $\frac{1}{4}$ and $1.$ 
>   As an example, we will compute the 
>   curvature of complex projective space.
>   The calculations for the other rank one spaces are similar.

Then they begin the example, which is numbered Example 3.38. The punchline is that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are orthogonal unit vectors, $J(\alpha)$ and $\beta$ are unit real vectors, so their real inner product lies between $-1$ and $1$ by Cauchy-Schwarz, followed by an identity about the sectional curvature that I shall write as
$$ K_{\alpha \beta} = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4} \langle J(\alpha), \beta \rangle^2.    $$

Comment: Thanks, Will, this is useful advice: To understand the $\frac{1}{4}$,
study the positive-curvature symmetric spaces!

Answer (score 6):

This was too long for a comment:

Certainly 1/4 is optimal, as Will Jagy points out, for e.g. the Fubini-Study metric on $CP^n$. The totally real tangent planes have curvature 1 (tangent to a totally geodesic $RP^2$), and the complex-invariant tangent planes to a totally geodesic $CP^1$ have curvature $1/4$. This is usually computed via the Riemannian submersion $S^{2n+1}\to CP^n$, but I think one can get a feel for this geometrically, by thinking about a quotient of $S^{2n+1}/U(1)=CP^n$. If you have $S^3/U(1)$, you get $CP^1$, and the map is the Hopf fibration. $S^3$ is the 3-sphere of radius 1, and when you quotient by $U(1)$, you get a sphere of half the diameter, since the circles of the Hopf fibration are distance $\pi/2$ apart, and thus the curvature is $1/4$. On the other hand, the $RP^n\subset CP^n$ subspaces are just a 2-fold quotient of a totally real $S^n\subset S^{2n+1}$ by the antipodal map, so have curvature $1$.

I saw Brendle give a talk about their theorem. One thing to note is that they have a local pinching theorem (pointwise), which is much stronger than a global pinching theorem. I think they actually show that they get positive isotropic curvature, which has something to do with complexifying the curvature tensor (this was introduced by Micallef-Moore I think), and is important for studying the stability of minimal 2-spheres. But I don't recall the details to be able to explain where $1/4$ comes in, but it has to do something with obtaining positive eigenvalues after complexifying the curvature tensor appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, Ian, especially for the reminder that pointwise pinching is much stronger than global pinching!

Answer (score 6):

The number $1/4$ allows them to use a lemma by Berger to show that $M \times \mathbb{R}^2$ has non-negative isotropy curvature for a pointwise quarter-pinched manifold $M$. Non-negative isotropy curvature condition is preserved by Ricci flow.

Berger's lemma says that if the sectional curvatures at a point $p$ are bounded by $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$, then the Riemann curvature tensor satisfies $R(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4) \leq \frac{2}{3}(\kappa_2 - \kappa_1)$ for all orthonormal four-frames $\{e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4\}$ at $p$. The reference for this lemma is M. Berger, *Sur quelques vari\'{e}t\'{e}s riemanniennes suffisamment pinc\'{e}es*, Bull. Soc. Math. France 88, 57-71(1960).

A related result is that Yau and Zheng showed that a negatively $1/4$-pinched manifold has non-positive complex sectional curvature from this lemma. See S. T. Yau and F. Zheng, *Negatively $1/4$-pinched riemannian metric on a compact K\"{a}hler manifold*, Invent. Math., 103, 527-535(1991).

Comment: So this reduced the problem to «why is there a $\frac23$ in Berger's result?» :) 

Comment: I just want to clarify the last part of Agol's answer. I don't think I can answer Joseph's original question. 